# "Error: The target entry-point has missing dependencies" using js library in Angular 12 app (but it works in Angular 8 app)

Tags: angular, angular-library, angular12

I have 2 custom libraries, let's call them lib1 and lib2.

lib2 is a js library, and lib1 uses lib2 to create Angular components. I want to use lib1 in my Angular 12 app. I have both lib1 and lib2 installed and they are in my node_modules. However, whenever I run `ng serve` I get the following error:
`Error: The target entry-point "lib1" has missing dependencies: node_modules/lib2/dist/js/app.js`

This path is used in lib1 components like so: `import {Button} from 'node_modules/lib2/dist/js/app.js'`.

This is confusing because that path does exist in the project. I have tried deleting node_modules and package-lock.json and running npm install again, but to no avail. The even stranger thing is that this configuration is working fine in an Angular 8 app. So there must be something that has changed in Angular 12 that's breaking it, I just can't figure out what. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is lib2 a dependency of lib1? Also, it is not a good practice to use node_module paths when importing things... You should set up your libraries properly and do `import { ... } from 'lib2'`